# SoapClient error fallback in PHP

Tags: soap, soap-client, php, php-5.2

In PHP, if you try to instantiate a new [`SoapClient`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php), and the WSDL is not accessible (server down or whatever), a PHP fatal error is thrown:

> Fatal error: SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL:
>   Couldn't load from
>   'http://example.com/servlet/app/SomeService?wsdl'
>   : failed to load external entity
>   "http://example.com/servlet/app/SomeService?wsdl"

Fatal errors in PHP, as far as I know, are not recoverable.

Is there any way to fallback from this? Can this fatal error somehow be avoided?

---

**Edit:** I should say that I am running on PHP 5.2, if it makes any difference.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This has already been discussed :

- https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=47584
- http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php#104046

Rasmus himself proposed the following solution:

```
<?php  
try {  
    $x = @new SoapClient("non-existent.wsdl",array("exceptions" => 1));  
} catch (SoapFault $E) {  
    echo $E->faultstring; 
}  
echo "ok\n";
```

Comment: Unfortunately this solution does not seem to work in PHP 5.3.10.

Comment: I copied it verbatim into a fresh file and it is not getting to the echo "Ok"; part.

Comment: But, when I looked further down I did find the notes about disabling xdebug and that allowed the above to work.

Answer (score 0):

See this topic [How do I catch a PHP Fatal Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277224/how-do-i-catch-a-php-fatal-error)

Basically you cant recover from a fatal error but you can provide a better experience to the user when registering a shutdown function

```
register_shutdown_function('handleShutdown');
function handleShutdown(){
    $error = error_get_last();
    if($error !== NULL){
        echo "Sorry for the inconvenience, an error just occurred.";
    }
}
```

Comment: best practice is try catch for sure.