# SoapFault exception not called in PHP 5.4

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl

I am trying to test Soap client. I want to see that if the service is down the SoapFault exception is thrown. So here is what I did:

```
$this->_server = 'http://XXXXXXXX.XXXXXXXX.nl/XXXX.ws/prsdfsfdows.asmx?WSDL';
try {
        $client = new SoapClient($this->_server, array('trace' => 1, 'exception' => 1));
    } catch (SoapFault $e) {
        var_dump($e);
        exit;
    }
```

I purposely misspelled the server url to be sure that the soap service is down.

I would expect to get a SoapFaultException. In stead I get an `E_ERROR`

> (dev) E_ERROR:  SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from
>   'http://XXXXX.XXXXXXXX.nl/XXXX.ws/prsdfsfdows.asmx?WSDL' : Premature
>   end of data in tag html line 1  in
>   /var/www/site/web/library/my/webservice.php:60
>
> 0 triggerError() called at [/var/www/site/web/library/ErrorHandler.php:212]
>   1 triggerFatalError() called at [unknown:unknown]

I'm running on PHP 5.4.39

Any suggestions?

### EDIT

Some more information:

I was notified about [this](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=47584) php bug it turns out that it could be that it has to do with xdebug. So now I have altered my code to :

```
    try {
        if(function_exists('xdebug_disable')) {
            xdebug_disable();
        }

        $client = @new SoapClient($this->_server, array("exceptions"=> 1));
        $this->setClient($client);
        xdebug_enable();
    } catch (SoapFault $ex) {
        echo 'soapfault';
        echo $ex->getTraceAsString();
        exit;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
```

But I still see the E_ERROR in stead of the `SoapFault`

Comment: `I'm running on PHP 6.4.39` Misspelled?

Comment: @Daan yes sorry fixed it

Comment: Does the following make sense? http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php#refsect1-soapclient.soapclient-errors

Comment: @OfirBaruch well I am sending a WSDL so i guess I'm running in WSDL mode, which means that I should get a `SoapFault` exception

Comment: Found the following answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6608086/soapclient-error-fallback-in-php/6608204#6608204

Comment: @OfirBaruch I tried that one already but didn't work for me